# why the icon not display on list using angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to display a icon on each item of list .but `caret` icon not display on first item of list .I need this icon display `right` side of item of list .

**secondly** when I click on `icon` it is not displaying dropdown list .it is capturing click event of `li` how to capture 'icon' click event

here is my code
http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/mEmyGG

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-controller='cntr'>
        <ul class="view-list">
            <li ng-repeat="d in data" ng-click="selectView(d, $event)">
                <a href="#">{{d.name}}</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. There is no icon in your code. Also, How could you expect a `caret` to be displayed if there is no `caret` class in your scss?

Comment: I am using bootsrap icon ..please see code pen

Answer (score 0):

try to update your scss with this code

```
.view-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    width: 100px;
  }
  li {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    >div {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
  .selected {
    background-color: blue;
    a {
      color: #ffffff;
    }
  }
}
```

The issue because you put width: 100% on the .view-list a
and you also need to specifiy the display of div inside the li to be 'inline-block'

and for seconde issue. do not forget to define jquery (required by bootstrap) and bootstrap on the script part.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update your HTML to:

```
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='cntr'>
    <ul class="view-list">
      <li ng-repeat="d in data" ng-click="selectView(d, $event)">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            {{d.name}}
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  <div>
</div>
```

The dropdown is using JavaScript. You have to add `jQuery` and `Bootstrap JavaScript` file in your page.

See updated demo: [Here](http://codepen.io/huychau/pen/yJbNVg)